# setting pin when using BluetoothListener

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, windows-ce

I'm making an android app to connect to a program on a WIN CE PC, whith the WIN CE PC as a server.

using the following code

```
 bluetoothListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
 bluetoothListener.Start();
 con = bluetoothListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();            
 updateUI("Client has connected");
 mStream = con.GetStream();
```

This will prompt a pin request on the WIN CE PC the first I connect to it.
But because the program on the WIN CE PC has to run in the foreground , I can't use the WIN CE prompt to enter the pin.

Is it possible to set the pin on the WIN CE side so it will not prompt a pin entry window and I can always connect to it using the same pin I've set.

I would alse like to be able to change the Bluetooth name of the WIN CE PC using code , instead of changing it in de Device Menu.

Edit 1:

if I use

```
con = bluetoothListener.AcceptBluetoothClient(); 
con.SetPin("4567");
```

It sets the pin but only for the next time I connect with it.
And if I use

```
con.SetPin("4567");
con = bluetoothListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
```

I get a NullReferenceException because con is not yet declared.

Comment: Hi, Di you figure this thing out? thanks...